# Why doesn't my ssh ask for password?

Tags: ssh, centos, login

I created a user 'bbword' on my remote CentoOs a while ago and it belongs to the group 'wheel'. I just changed its password. I have two questions:

1) On my current user, after I execute "su bbword" & "ls", it displays:
   "ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied"
   Why can't I even view the directory?

2) When I "ssh" from my local machine to this remote machine with the user 'bbword', it doesn't even ask for a password. I log in successfully without password. However, it even asks for a password for the 'root' user with ssh. Why is that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question 1 is that when you execute the `su` command, you are still in the directory of your original user.  The `bbword` user may not have x permission on your user's home directory.

Comment: But the "bbword" is in the 'wheel' group, which functions as a root user. Right?

Comment: The `wheel` group permits users to become root.  The `wheel` group does not create superusers.